# using VBA copying data from different files in a folder to master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code on a master sheet when I press a button it goes through the folder that I want and opens and closes the sheets where it should extract data from.

Here is the code I have for opening and closing the files from the button on the master sheet. I need help to write a code for the space ###CODE GOES HERE in the below code. I have been pulling my hair out.

```
Public Sub test()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Path = "\\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\CSV Supplier Main\Inbox folder\"  'CHANGE PATH
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")

 Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
    '
    ' ###CODE GOES HERE
    '  
   wbk.Close True
   Filename = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

Can you please help me write a code in

This code for '###CODE GOES HERE' needs to get the data from the opening sheets rows by checking if there is a value in a specific column. For example, if there is data in L12.Then in the opening sheet, it will copy J8 J9 and L12 in master sheet a2 c2 and e2.

Then in the opening sheet, it checks L13. IF there is value it copies J8 J9 and L13 to a3 c3 and e3.

Then in the opened sheet checks L14...

Until L20

Then the opened workbook is closed and it opens the next workbook in the folder. Checks the same table:if there is data in L12.Then in the opening sheet, it will copy J8 J9 and L12 in master sheet put in the next free row.

This is is supplier timesheet

[supplier timesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1q5j.jpg)

[master sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icrhv.jpg)

Comment: Can you post an image of your data? And desired result? I am unclear on the relationship between opening sheet, master sheet and same table. When you say open next sheet etc do you mean workbook? What file types are you actually wanting to process? Are they actually CSVs or *.xl*?

Comment: Hi added the image of the worksheet where the data is gotten from. The worksheet where the data is extract is XLSM. The master file is also XLSM. The desired results would be to fill out a table on the master sheet. Hope this clarifies. Let me know if I need to clarify anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. The code is using for both master and opening the first worksheet with index 1. Change the index if needed:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim wksMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    Path = "\\ttsnas02\user_mdocs$\tdf8273\Documents\Rob\External supplier timesheet\CSV Supplier Main\Inbox folder\"  'CHANGE PATH
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")

    ' bind the master worksheet to access it later on
    ' change index if needed
    Set wksMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' or ThisWorkbook
    i = 2

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)

        ' loop through range in worksheet with index 1 (the first)
        ' change index if needed
        With wkb.Worksheets(1)
            For Each rng In .Range("L12:L20")
                ' if there is a value in the cell
                If rng <> vbNullString Then
                    wksMaster.Range("A" & i) = .Range("J8")
                    wksMaster.Range("C" & i) = .Range("J9")
                    wksMaster.Range("E" & i) = rng
                    ' increment i
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With

        wkb.Close True
        Filename = Dir

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time with my problem. This works perfectly!! What does 'change index if needed' mean?

Comment: Also if you can I need the code copied data to be inserted in the next blank row on the master workbook. Not sure where to insert this since you the 'i = i +1'?

Comment: Another final thing. If you have the time. As you can see on the pics in the original post that I have just added. In column B cell 12 there is the date. With the hours worked corresponding in cell i12. Depending on the date compared to the week ending date in cell i6. The hours need to go in a particular column in the master sheet. Looking at the master sheet pic this may make more sense. e.g. if there is 4 hours worked on the 15th it will go in column K. if 5 hours worked on the 17th it will go in column M. Hope this makes sense. Thank you mysterious person.

Comment: 'i = 2' sets the first row in master, change it to 'i = 3'. Meaning of index: the code line wkb.Worksheets(1) uses the first sheet, the index is 1.